# NodeJs step by step execution my actions

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I have some problem. 
I have mini socket server.

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        // here i do xml parsing and run some action
        var xml2js = require('xml2js'), parser = new xml2js.Parser();
        parser.addListener('end', function(result) {
            var command = require(result['@']['action']);
            var c = new command(socket);
            c.run();
        }).parseString(data);
    });
});        
server.listen('8081', '127.0.0.1');
```

Good, but if i send many commands to server
like this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8081
<query action="some_action1"></query>
<query action="some_action2"></query>
<query action="some_action3"></query>
```

My server is executing this action is asynchronous. How i can get running this actions is step by step ?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0):

You need to make queue(FIFO) out of your commands. And execute those in order server getem.

Comment: but this does not help in the implementation of synchronous

Comment: your server will run your actions step by step if you will run them one after another. Even if your server asynchronous.